# GitHub OAuth redirect through frontend proxy blocked by CORS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webpack, oauth, cors

#### What I am trying to do

I've got a JS frontend that has webpack, and I'm routing the /api requests to a backend server like so:

```json
proxy: {
    '/api': {
        target: 'https://[::1]:5001',
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true,
    }
}
```

And a .NET 5 backend that has cors enabled for all origins and headers and methods.

```cs
app.UseCors(x => x
    .AllowAnyOrigin()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader());
```

This backend is trying to authenticate people with GitHub, as so.

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "GitHub";
            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddOAuth("GitHub", options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = GitHubConfiguration.ClientId;
                options.ClientSecret = GitHubConfiguration.ClientSecret;
                options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/api/signin-github");
                options.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;

                options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize";
                options.TokenEndpoint = "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token";
                options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://api.github.com/user";

                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "id");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "name");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:github:login", "login");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:github:url", "html_url");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:github:avatar", "avatar_url");

                options.Events = new OAuthEvents
                {
                    OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
                    {
                        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
                        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);

                        var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                        var user = JsonDocument.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                        context.RunClaimActions(user.RootElement);
                    }
                };
            });
```

Pretty standard, from what I can tell.

To test it out I've got this endpoint

```cs
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class AccountController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" });
        }
```

This works pretty well when I call it directly in a browser at

```sh
https://localhost:5001/api/account/login
```

But when I try and git that endpoint from my frontend, I'm getting

> Access to fetch at 'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&scope=&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5001%2Fapi%2Fsignin-github&state=<OAUTH_STATE>' (redirected from 'https://localhost:5001/api/account/login') from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Here's a basic summary of from fiddler:

```sh
GET https://localhost:5001/api/account/login
302 Redirect to https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?etc

GET https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?etc
302 Redirect to https://github.com/login?etc
```

There aren't any exceptions of logs in the server.

What seems to be happening is frontend -> backend is working fine, but then the backend is trying to redirect the frontend which isn't allowed due to cross origin limitations.

Am I correct in thinking that I need to somehow get the redirect to hit the server instead of what it still thinks is the origin (as the webpack dev server proxy is keeping the origin as `localhost:8081` even after the request is proxies)? If so, how do I then respond to the frontend?

I've been round in circles for a couple of hours with this, so any push in the right direction would be great.

Cheers,

EDIT Here's a closer look at the headers coming back from that last redirect that's causing it:

```
GET https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=<oauthinfo>
Host: github.com
Connection: keep-alive
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Origin: null
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://localhost:8081/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9


HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Mon, 26 Apr 2021 21:27:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Vary: X-PJAX
permissions-policy: interest-cohort=()
Location: https://github.com/login?client_id=<oauthinfo>
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Expect-CT: max-age=2592000, report-uri="https://api.github.com/_private/browser/errors"
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; base-uri 'self'; block-all-mixed-content; connect-src 'self'
Vary: Accept-Encoding, Accept, X-Requested-With
X-GitHub-Request-Id: D17E:70F9:663C530:5A21FA1:7097304C
Content-Length: 545
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't realise that you can't do an authentication flow using a regular fetch GET.

The configuration was correct, and using

```js
window.location.href('https://localhost:5001/api/account/login')
```

in the JS or using a link such as

```html
<a href='https://localhost:5001/api/account/login'>
  Login to GitHub
</a>
```

Fixed my issue.

The reason is simple, and one I overlooked. You need to make the request to the server directly, which then allows you to go through the whole authentication flow independent of the front-end, allowing you to forego any keys in the front-end that could be less secure.

At the end of the flow, you're redirected back to the front-end, fully authenticated.

Answer (score -1):

It seem your application is being redirect(302) back and forth from http=>https and again its going in same loop. Make the https request and enable https for your local end point. It should work then

Comment: Are you sure? The fiddler summary shows `frontend` -> `backend` -> `https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize` -> tries to redirect to `https://github.com/login`, which I assume is where the frontend login (into github) would occur?

Comment: @PotterJam Refer this document https://github.com/travisghansen/external-auth-server/issues/57

Comment: In the proxy config I've already got `Headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", https: true }`, and https didn't make any difference (just reduced the number of tunnels). I've updated my post with the new fiddler output.

Comment: Could you post the whole startup code of  API pls? Cors has a lot of rules,  and it is very important to see the whole picture.

Comment: @Sergey Here's the whole startup file, and it's just running through the default web server (kestral) https://gist.github.com/PotterJam/47c9712f60d868f0255078c2f1b7c08b